# Gridview select the DataTextField vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

with a column. When I click the item there I want to redirect me to other page, but in my way that I did,it doesn't work. So I would like if you could help me.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Width="100%" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"     OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <Columns>
                                   <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Select" ButtonType="Button" DataTextField="region_name">
                                   <ItemStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large" HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
                                   </asp:ButtonField>
                            </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and this is the code on selectedchange

```
 Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.SelectedRow()
    Response.Redirect("Regions.aspx?region=" & row.Cells(0).Text)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is failing?  How is it responding right now?

The main issue i see right now is that you are not using your Select Command.  At the Gridview element you need to add a RowCommand attribute.  Then in that method do your code and redirect.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.